# what's the meaning of exit code of program with empty void main()?

Tags: c, linux, shell, gcc, exit-code

I made a simple C program with empty main as given below and compiled it with gcc

```
void main(){
}
```

upon execution, it return exit code as `25`,
and if I add a printf statement,after including stdio.h, it returns exit code `5`

what's the meaning of `25` and `5` here and why it's being returned by whatever code that is executed before or after main()?
exit code is zero if I use int main() and don't put a return statement.

Comment: The question headline says you have `void main()`, but the question body says you're executing a program with `int main()`. Please clarify.

Comment: If you compiled in C99 mode or later, the exit status must be zero.  In C90 mode, it is indeterminate.

Comment: Probably return code will be different with different length printf's (`printf("five\n");` or `printf("2\n");`).

Comment: @JohnBollinger edited question to clarify

Comment: @pmg return value is the length of printed string

Comment: @pmg it might be due to untouched eax register after printf statement, from manlio's answer,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

(Adding on John Bollinger's answer)

### * void main

The old ISO C Standard (ISO/IEC 9899:1999) stated:

> [main] shall be defined
>
> - with a return type of `int` and
>
>   - with no parameters […] or
>   - with two parameters […] or equivalent; 
>       or
>   - in some other implementation-defined manner.

<sup>§ 5.1.2.2.1 ¶ 1 of the C Standard</sup>

> If the return type is not compatible with `int`, the termination status returned to the host environment is unspecified.

<sup>§ 5.1.2.2.3 ¶ 1</sup>

which indicates that allowing forms that didn't return `int` was intentional.

Many compiler's manuals (e.g. Watcom C/C++, IBM VisualAge C/C++, Microsoft Visual C/C++) stated that `main` may have the return type `void` so a program with `void main()` was a conforming program.

For a long time much code was written with a return type of `void`. `gcc` (probably) consider important to be compatible with legacy code and allows `void main()` but in that case:

- it gives a warning (`warning: return type of ‘main’ is not ‘int’`);
- the return value of the program is undefined.

References:

- http://web.archive.org/web/20160604095048/homepage.ntlworld.com/jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/legality-of-void-main.html

### * int main

`int main() {}`

This is undefined in C89/90 and well defined in following versions (where it returns `0`).

### * actual value

On x86 the `EAX` register is normally used for return values. So

```
int main() {}
```

is compiled to something like:

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     eax, 0
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

For

```
void main() {}
```

the simplest action is removing `mov eax, 0`:

```
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

If you add a `printf` statement:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
  printf("1234");
}
```

you get:

```
.LC0:
        .string "1234"
main:
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     edi, OFFSET FLAT:.LC0
        mov     eax, 0
        call    printf
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

The `printf` call alters the `EAX` register (returns the number of characters written to the stream, and `EAX` is used for the return value).

Answer (score 5):

> what's the meaning of 25 and 5 here

The C language specifications do not define behavior for a program whose `main()` is declared to return `void`.  Implementations that nevertheless accept such code may or may not define behavior for it.  In a general sense, then, *no* exit statuses have any meaning or significance for a program with `void main()`.

Apparently, GCC in particular does accept the code, but I find no definition for its behavior among [GCC's documented C extensions](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-9.3.0/gcc/#toc-Extensions-to-the-C-Language-Family), so neither in that particular case do the exit statuses you observe have any meaning.

> and why it's being returned by
>   whatever code that is executed before or after main()?

No particular reason.  The behavior is undefined.

> exit code is
>   zero if I use int main() and don't put a return statement.

That case is well defined.  C specifies that if execution reaches the end of the initial call to `main()` (presumed declared with one of the two C-standard signatures, both of which return `int`) then the behavior is as if `exit(0)` were called.  This is a special case.  The behavior is otherwise undefined if execution reaches the closing brace of a non-`void` function, and its caller does anything with the return value.

Comment: From a pure implementation point of view, the reason that OP got those return values is that GCC doesn't write anything into the return value register when returning from a void function (because why would it?), but the `_start` code reads from that register after `main` returns because it expects `main` to return an `int`. So the result will be whatever happened to be in that register when `main` returned.